# zPosition in SpriteKit isn't working

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a Pop The Lock game. There is a circle and a person. I want the person to be in front of the circle (the person should be placed on top of the circle). I tried using the zPosition method but it doesn't seem to work. Here is the code of the GameScene.swift file.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {


    var Circle = SKSpriteNode()
    var Person = SKSpriteNode()
    var Path = UIBezierPath()
    var gameStarted = Bool()



    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
            //Changing the background color of the view



            //Creating the Cirle
        Circle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle")
        Circle.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
        Circle.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
            self.addChild(Circle)

            //Creating the person
        Person = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Person")
        Person.size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 7)
        Person.position = CGPoint(x:  self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2 + 115)
        Person.zPosition = 1

            //Rotating the Person By 90 degrees
        Person.zRotation = 3.14 / 2
          self.addChild(Person)

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

           Person.zPosition = 1




               if gameStarted == false{
            MoveClockwise()


        } else if gameStarted == true {


        }




    }

    func MoveClockwise(){




        let dx = Person.position.x - self.frame.width / 2
        let dy = Person.position.y - self.frame.height / 2

        let rad = atan2(dy, dx)


       Path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2), radius: self.frame.width / 2, startAngle: rad, endAngle: rad + CGFloat(M_PI * 4), clockwise: true)

        let follow = SKAction.followPath(Path.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 200)

        Person.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow).reversedAction())

    }

    func MoveCounterClockwise(){

    }


    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Comment: Just set circle.zPosition = 1 and person.zPosition = 2

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with zPosition. The problem is the scene's size is not the same as the view's size. In your `didMoveToView`, set `scaleMode = .ResizeFill` and change `self.frame` to `view.frame`.

Comment: 0x141E and Whirlwind, thank you so much! It really helped. I really appreciate it :) Both the methods worked, surprisingly